# Delete rows from WebTable which contain only 15 rows

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

I am automating a web application using Katalon studio with Selenium/Java. In a web table where we have to keep only first 15 records and rest of the records should be deleted. Each page contains 25 rows of data. The following is the code I have written but when I execute it deletes only 25 records and it stops. The code must delete the rows till it reaches 15, e.g. from 200 records to 15 records.

```
   public void deleteRows() {
        int rows_count;
        int Row;
        WebElement UsersTable;
        WebElement UsersTable2;
        List<WebElement> rows_UsersTable;
        List<WebElement> cols_UserTable;
        int cols_count;
        int rowsNeeded = 15;
        WebDriverWait wait;
        List<WebElement> rows_UsersTable2;

        UsersTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody"));
        rows_UsersTable = UsersTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        rows_count = rows_UsersTable.size();
        println ("Total rows is  " +rows_count)
        
        cols_UserTable = UsersTable.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td"));
        cols_count = cols_UserTable.size();
        println ("Total columns is " +cols_count)

        if (rows_count >= rowsNeeded) {
            int j = 1;
            int newRowCount;
            
            while (j <= rows_count) {
                WebElement deleteIcon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table/tbody/tr/td)[last()]/span"));
                String text = deleteIcon.getText();
                deleteIcon.click();

                Thread.sleep(2000);

                WebElement confirmBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Confirm']"));
                confirmBtn.click();

                Thread.sleep(3000);

                println ("Successfully deleted " + j);

                UsersTable2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody"));
                rows_UsersTable2 = UsersTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

                newRowCount = rows_UsersTable2.size();
                println ("The new row count is " + newRowCount)
                j++;
            }
       }
   }
```

I know there is something I have missed, please help.

Thanks

Comment: "Each page contains 25 rows of data" - wouldn't that mean that your code should only delete up to 10 rows? I'm not sure using Selenium to "delete" pages that haven't been displayed or to drive the backend directly would be a good idea.

Comment: @RamN is "rows_count" contains No of rows on first page or all the rows of including hidden pages?

If its contains only first page rows, you have to store new 'newRowCount' value to 'rows_count' at end of the while loop

Comment: @Optimworks, rows_count contains only the first page rows. I will assign the 'newRowCount' to 'rows_count' and try. Thanks.

Comment: @Optimworks I tried it and working fine but it is deleting only till row 16. The code should exit only when the row_count equals 15. Any idea what am I missing?